# Upload Download from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've made use of a script which is available online. The File upload.php allows the user to upload a file and then store the selected file in the MySQL database. 
    Later the download.php script displays the links for all the files stored in the database. When the user clicks the link, the file should be downloaded. I've enclosed the script below.
    But the problem is, I am not using any upload.php nor download .php.
    I have tried this in wordpress using "php code for post (Only shortcode placed ion the page)" at one shot.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)

{

$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];

$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fileType = (get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 0 ? mysql_real_escape_string(
$_FILES['userfile']['type']) :
mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_FILES['userfile'])));

$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');

$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));

$content = addslashes($content);

fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())

{

$fileName = addslashes($fileName);

}

mysql_connect("localhost","*****","***");

mysql_select_db("****");

$query = "INSERT INTO wp3_cte (FileupName, size, type, content ) ".

"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

echo "File $fileName uploaded";

}

?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="246">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />

<input id="userfile" type="file" name="userfile" /></td>
<td width="80"><input id="upload" type="submit" name="upload" value=" Upload " /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Download File From MySQL Database</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
          charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>


<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","**********","**********");
mysql_select_db("**********");
$query = "SELECT id, FileupName FROM wp3_cte";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo "Database is empty <br>";
 } else {
 while (list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 ?>
<a href="download.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($id); ?>"
               ><?php echo urlencode($name); ?></a> <br>
            <?php
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
mysql_connect("localhost","**********","**********");
mysql_select_db("**********");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT FileupName, type, size, content"FROM wp3_cte WHERE id = '$id'";
           $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
           list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $content;
mysql_close();
exit;
  }
  ?>  


  The problem i am facing is in this peace of code:`download.php`.

 Uploaded file is showing properly if i click on download file blank page appears.

 Id is displayed in Url

 The uploaded file is saving in some folder named upload in ftp server i tried a lot but i was out with no result.
 can any one help me Thanks in advance!!!!
```

Comment: Hi JMR. I always make download scripts without flush() and ob_clean() which works great. Does your $size has the correct value?

Comment: How often have people asked variations of this question? The short answer is DONT SAVE IMAGES IN THE DB

Comment: Hi Klaus.Yes $size has the correct value....According to your suggestion tried changing the code without  flush() and ob_clean() but still its not working....it seems like download.php is the error <a href="download.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($id); ?>"
                   ><?php echo urlencode($name); ?></a> <br>

Comment: Hi e4c5, i have tried in different ways of code but still could not get expected output.I tried storing files in a folder even though there was no result!...